# Disallow all urls that starts with a string

Tags: google-search

I have a multi-language website with four languages. I added a fifth one (Russian), but I did not want its links to appear on search results, because it was used for something specific not for search and users to see. They are dynamic links, so I searched and I added it to my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /ru
```

A lot said to use it like this so any url that starts with this string "/ru" will be disallowed.
But all the pages got indexed in google and are appearing in search results. I did not submit any sitemap for it, nor did I share it anywhere, so I am not sure how did it get in search results. How can I tell google to remove them from the index and just ignore them? I would have used the removal tool, but they are too many (more than 1500 link).